# Using Left and char index is returning an invalid parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I combine left and charindex I am getting an invalid parameter for left

my row returns something like productname,productupc,some other text
I only want to get the productname

so by using charindex I can get the total chars until the first comma

using charindex(',',[column name])

example

[productinformation] for column name

this is the full column returned

```
 select [productinformation] from testTable
```

blue widget,1313138, 300 pcs in a box

```
 select charindex(',',[productinformation]) from testTable
```

would return 12

using
     select left([productinformation]),charindex(',',[productinformation])) from testTable

returns

```
 blue widget,
```

Using
     select charindex(','[productinformation]) -1 from testTable
returns 11

So I would assume subtracting one from the charindex would give  me just the product name.

```
 SELECT  left([productinformation],charindex(','[productinformation])-1) FROM testTable
```

returns

```
 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function
```

Comment: What is 0 minus 1? `select left('irrelevant text', charindex(',','text value that does not contain a comma') -1)`

Comment: Is the missing comma in `charindex(','[productinformation])` just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter is not found `CHARINDEX` will return 0 and thus the `LEFT` function is given a negative value (when 1 is subtracted from 0), and this is what's causing the invalid length error.  You can use a `CASE..WHEN` statement to avoid this.

```
SELECT LEFT([PRODUCTINFORMATION],
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [PRODUCTINFORMATION]) = 0 THEN LEN([PRODUCTINFORMATION]) ELSE
CHARINDEX(',', [PRODUCTINFORMATION]) - 1 END) AS PRODUCTINFORMATION
FROM TESTTABLE
```

Comment: This is correct if you add -1 in the else clause of the case statement.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @jyao, I updated my post to omit the typo.

Comment: What if _CHARINDEX()_ Return 0? in your code it mean 1-1=0, that will give wrong result cause the char is exists.

Comment: @Sami if CHARINDEX returns 0 then the code would exit on the first condition in the CASE statement, which checks for this and just uses the length of the column without subtracting 1.  The subsequent ELSE would not be reached.

Answer (score 3):

The **[`LEFT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function recive only  positive integer

> integer_expression
>   Is a positive integer that specifies how many characters of the character_expression will be returned. If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned. If integer_expression is type bigint and contains a large value, character_expression must be of a large data type such as varchar(max).

So, if your `CHARINDEDX()` does not find the char it will return `0`, and you add `-1`, so `0-1` which is `-1`.

That will throw an error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

You need to check if the returned value is positive or not

```
SELECT LEFT([productinformation],
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',[productinformation]) > 1
                 THEN CHARINDEX(',',[productinformation]) - 1
                 WHEN CHARINDEX(',',[productinformation]) = 1
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE LEN([productinformation]) --if you want to return it all otherwise 0
                 -- if you set it to 0 it will return ''
            END
           )
FROM testTable
```

Comment: You just point out the reason of the error, but it would be better if you put the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try substring

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING([productinformation], 0, CHARINDEX(',', [productinformation])) FROM testTable
```